# ASP.NET login form using different tables

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I just want an ASP.NET login form using different tables so if anyone can help me. Here  is what I am doing.

```
try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();

            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Users.Email, Users.Password ,Admin.Email, Admin.Password FROM Users,Admin WHERE Email ='" + Email.Text.Trim() + "' AND Password='" + password.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Successful login');</script>");
                    Session["status"] = dr["Fullname"].ToString();                      
                }

            }
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            }
            else if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Users.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid credentials');</script>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well you might want to brush up on your SQL and implement a correct join first.

Comment: You also should learn about using SqlParameters to parametrise your query as its dreadfully unsafe as it is.

Comment: And I truly hope you are not storing your password as plain text - if you are lookup hashing and salting.

Comment: Read up on those topics

Comment: Also please ask a question in a post, since you don't do so we would have to guess what you are trying to achieve. To get a decisive answer you'd need to ask a well formulated question with some examples.

Comment: Is this for a school assignment? Then it might be best to say so. As Dale mentioned, people will probably not help you in creating anything that has such large security problems, I won't either.